# Error while treating data with curve_fit : " RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded."

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I have to do an homework on Python, and I'm getting the error :

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded." while treating data.
```

So, I just understand that it was coming from the function `curve_fit`. But I can't understand what is wrong with my data.

Here is the program :

```py
%matplotlib inline
# Packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import csv

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})

## Birch-Murnaghan EOS
def BM(V,K0,Kp0,V0):
    return 3/2*K0*((V0/V)**(7/3)-(V0/V)**(5/3))*(1-3/4*(4-Kp0)*((V0/V)**(2/3)-1))

data = pd.read_excel("data1.xlsx")
P = data['P'].to_numpy()
V = data['V'].to_numpy()

popt, pcov = curve_fit(BM, V, P, p0 = [100,4,200],bounds=(0,np.inf))
K0 = popt[0]
Kp0 = popt[1]
V0 = popt[2]

print('Fitted parameters:')
print('K0=',K0, 'GPa')
print('Kp0=',Kp0)
print('V0=',V0)

V_fit = np.linspace(135,175,500)

plt.plot(V,P,'d',color='tab:blue')
plt.plot(V_fit,BM(V_fit,*popt),color='tab:blue')

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('V ()')
plt.ylabel('P (Gpa)')
```

And the data I have to fit :

Data 1 with high temperature samples, Name : DataHT

```
P;V
26,53;149,3425735
28,52;147,568721
31;147,7667799
43,17;142,4455489
43,48;142,2264883
43,9;141,1969164
45,11;141,8507811
45,9;141,7570371
47,49;140,8463664
48,33;140,8081866
49,51;140,6694272
49,59;140,506616
49,59;140,7843717
54,33;138,9670569
```

Data 2 with high temperature samples, Name : DataLT

```
P;V
32,55;149,4445136
45,81;143,9685449
52,88;142,8895768
56,14;141,4887467
47,34;144,4700032
51,52;143,1595805
34,88;150,1350425
48,72;143,9327471
57,53;141,3831252
55,73;142,1690598
37,46;149,7317374
40,26;150,2580983
```

I understood that I have to change the Name of the data file I import, but I don't get why do I get an error.

The things is my teacher ask me to plot one curve fo each set of data and then give the fitted parameters. Here is an example:

[image]

Could someone help me both plotting the data sets and having the fitted parameters ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you have the fit parameters, where do you get the error

Comment: do you expect me to type in all the data points, why not post a CSV version of the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical problems - poor estimates, no graphing of estimates. This succeeds:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, Bounds


def datasets() -> tuple[
    tuple[
        str,     # dataset name
        tuple[   # dataset
            tuple[float, float],  # PV coordinate
            ...
        ],
    ],
    ...
]:
    return (
        (
            'hitemp',
            (
                (26.53, 149.3425735),
                (28.52, 147.568721 ),
                (31.00, 147.7667799),
                (43.17, 142.4455489),
                (43.48, 142.2264883),
                (43.90, 141.1969164),
                (45.11, 141.8507811),
                (45.90, 141.7570371),
                (47.49, 140.8463664),
                (48.33, 140.8081866),
                (49.51, 140.6694272),
                (49.59, 140.506616 ),
                (49.59, 140.7843717),
                (54.33, 138.9670569),
            ),
        ),
        (
            'lotemp',
            (
                (32.55, 149.4445136),
                (45.81, 143.9685449),
                (52.88, 142.8895768),
                (56.14, 141.4887467),
                (47.34, 144.4700032),
                (51.52, 143.1595805),
                (34.88, 150.1350425),
                (48.72, 143.9327471),
                (57.53, 141.3831252),
                (55.73, 142.1690598),
                (37.46, 149.7317374),
                (40.26, 150.2580983),
            ),
        ),
    )


def birch_murnaghan(
    V: np.ndarray,
    K0: float, Kp0: float, V0: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Birch-Murnaghan equation of state
    """
    return (
        3/2*K0*(
            (V0/V)**(7/3) -
            (V0/V)**(5/3)
        )*(
            1
            - 3/4*(4-Kp0)*(
                (V0/V)**(2/3) - 1
            )
        )
    )


def main() -> None:
    fig: plt.Figure
    ax: plt.Axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    p0_sets = (
        (1.0, 350, 200),
        (0.5, 500, 210),
    )

    for (dataset_name, dataset), p0 in zip(datasets(), p0_sets):
        P, V = np.array(dataset).T

        popt, pcov = curve_fit(
            f=birch_murnaghan,
            xdata=V, ydata=P,
            p0=p0,
            bounds=Bounds(lb=(0,0,0)),
            maxfev=1_000,
        )

        K0, Kp0, V0 = popt
        print(f'{dataset_name} fit:')
        print(f'K0={K0:.3f} GPa')
        print(f'Kp0={Kp0:.1f}')
        print(f'V0={V0:.1f}')
        print()

        V_fit = np.linspace(V.min(), V.max(), num=500)
        P_est = birch_murnaghan(V_fit, *p0)
        P_fit = birch_murnaghan(V_fit, *popt)

        ax.scatter(V, P, label=f'{dataset_name} experiment')
        ax.plot(V_fit, P_est, label=f'{dataset_name} p0')
        ax.plot(V_fit, P_fit, label=f'{dataset_name} fit')

    ax.grid(True)
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_xlabel('V')
    ax.set_ylabel('P (Gpa)')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: estimate graphs]

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help ! However I edited my post to clarify what I needed to get after I've finished this task could you add something to get the fitted parameters here in you program ? 
I would have liked to try myself but when I'm copiing your code in my jupyterlab it's refusing to work. Here is the error : TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ub'
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ub'

Comment: Update scipy, then that problem should go away.